# Are there a set of $3\times3$ involutory matrices that form a basis?

Tags: matrices, involutions

My understanding is that any $2\times2$ matrix can be decomposed into the Pauli matrices and the $2\times2$ identity matrix, which are all involutory. Is there a set of $3\times3$ matrices which are also involutory and form a basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&-1},\ \pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&-1&0\\ 0&0&1},\ \pmatrix{-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1},
$$
$$
\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&1},\ \pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&1&0\\ 1&0&0},\ \pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&1&0},
$$
$$
\pmatrix{0&-i&0\\ i&0&0\\ 0&0&1},\ \pmatrix{0&0&-i\\ 0&1&0\\ i&0&0},\ \pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&-i\\ 0&i&0}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Did you derive this yourself, or is this mentioned in the literature somewhere?

Comment: @user1704042 I cooked it up. It's an easy modification of Pauli matrices.